# Sending mail from an application without using SMTP

Tags: api, email, outlook

I want to send mail from my utility or application to defaulters outlook mail. So I want to know whether Microsoft outlook exposes any endpoint for sending mail purpose.

Comment: Outlook mail REST API reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#SendMessages

Comment: Using what API? If you have Outlook installed locally, it is as easy to use Outlook Object Model (MailItem.Send is what you need).

Comment: API means using outlook mail rest endpoint can you send email to others directly without having any SMTP server configured.Send mail feature I have to implement in either java or python application. Can you please elaborate?